# Sum of specific index in 2-d list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

How can I use a for loop to print out and calculate the sum of the second character in each line
(2,6,8,2,6,8)?

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 2, 4], [5, 6,2], [7, 8, 9]]
s = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        s += a[i][j]
print(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop over the list's length and access each sublist by index:

```py
s = 0
for i in range(len(a)):
    s += a[i][1]
```

And of course, you could replace this with a generator expression:

```py
s = sum(x[1] for x in a)
```